# Set axis tight only to x or y axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a plot look like this:

[image]

Obviously, the left and right side is a waste of space, so I set

```
plt.axis('tight')
```

But this gives me plot like this:

[image]

The xlim looks right now, but the ylim is too tight for the plot.

I'm wondering, if I can only set `axis(tight)` only to x axis in my case?

So the plot may look something like this:

[image]

It's certainly possible that I can do this manually by

```
plt.gca().set_xlim(left=-10, right=360)
```

But I'm afraid this is not a very elegant solution.

Comment: Still trying to figure out why they have weird behavior as the default here.

Comment: More generally, you may also want to show, e.g., a *subset* of the plotted xrange, and have the yrange be tight for that narrow (in x) view of what was plotted.   Or vice versa. The accepted answer can be used for this too, ie. in general to set ytight or xtight independently (to use Matlab terminology)...

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You want to use matplotlib's [`autoscale`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.autoscale.html) method from the [`matplotlib.axes.Axes` class](https://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes).

[image]

Using the functional API, you apply a tight x axis using

```
plt.autoscale(enable=True, axis='x', tight=True)
```

or if you are using the object oriented API you would use

```
ax = plt.gca()  # only to illustrate what `ax` is
ax.autoscale(enable=True, axis='x', tight=True)
```

[image]

For completeness, the `axis` kwarg can take `'x'`, `'y'`, or `'both'`, where the default is `'both'`.

Comment: A small addition: I'm mostly using the object-oriented API, `autoscale` is actually a method of the `Axes` class.

Comment: This does not seem to work with the y-axes.  I tried `axis='y'` with no change.

Comment: @StevenC.Howell Works fine for y-axes with matplotlib up to version 2.2.2 both on Linux (Python 2) and on Windows (Python 3, 32-/64-bit versions).

Answer (score 3):

I just put the following at the beginning of those scripts in which I know I'll want my xlims to hug my data:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['axes.xmargin'] = 0
```

If I decide to add some whitespace buffer to an individual plot in that same script, I do it manually with:

```
plt.xlim(lower_limit, upper_limit)
```

While the accepted answer works, and is what I used for a while, I switched to this strategy because I only have to remember it once per script.