# How to get rid of extra white space on subplots with shared axes?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm creating a plot using python 3.5.1 and matplotlib 1.5.1 that has two subplots (side by side) with a shared Y axis. A sample output image is shown below:

[image: Sample Image]

Notice the extra white space at the top and bottom of each set of axes. Try as I might I can't seem to get rid of it. The overall goal of the figure is to have a waterfall type plot on the left with a shared Y axes with the plot on the right.

Here's some sample code to reproduce the image above.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
%matplotlib inline

# create some X values

periods = np.linspace(1/1440, 1, 1000)

# create some Y values (will be datetimes, not necessarily evenly spaced 
# like they are in this example)

day_ints = np.linspace(1, 100, 100)
days = pd.to_timedelta(day_ints, 'D') + pd.to_datetime('2016-01-01')

# create some fake data for the number of points 
points = np.random.random(len(day_ints))

# create some fake data for the color mesh

Sxx = np.random.random((len(days), len(periods)))

# Create the plots

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))

# create first plot

ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((1,5), (0,0), colspan=4)
im = ax1.pcolormesh(periods, days, Sxx, cmap='viridis', vmin=0, vmax=1)
ax1.invert_yaxis()
ax1.autoscale(enable=True, axis='Y', tight=True)

# create second plot and use the same y axis as the first one

ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((1,5), (0,4), sharey=ax1)    
ax2.scatter(points, days)
ax2.autoscale(enable=True, axis='Y', tight=True)

# Hide the Y axis scale on the second plot
plt.setp(ax2.get_yticklabels(), visible=False)    
#ax1.set_adjustable('box-forced') 
#ax2.set_adjustable('box-forced')

fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax1)
```

As you can see in the commented out code I've tried a number of approaches, as suggested by posts like https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/1789/ and [Matplotlib: set axis tight only to x or y axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37558329/matplotlib-set-axis-tight-only-to-x-or-y-axis).

As soon as I remove the `sharey=ax1` part of the second subplot2grid call the problem goes away, but then I also don't have a common Y axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autoscale tends to add a buffer to the data so that all of the data points are easily visible and not part-way cut off by the axes.

Change:

```
ax1.autoscale(enable=True, axis='Y', tight=True)
```

to:

```
ax1.set_ylim(days.min(),days.max())
```

and

```
ax2.autoscale(enable=True, axis='Y', tight=True)
```

to:

```
ax2.set_ylim(days.min(),days.max())
```

To get:

[image]

Comment: Normally I like the autoscaling "helping me", but when combined with an image (or something that looks like an image) the extra white space is annoying. Thanks, I've been fighting this all day.